# Creating a datamodule in background thread

Tags: image, delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, datamodule

I have a `TDatamodule` that has a `TImageCollection` (70 images) and 3 `TVirtualImageList`s.
Its creation take a lot of time. The `.dfm` file measures slightly over 400 kB.

I'd like to autocreate this datamodule because the images are used throughout the program.
But in the project source the `Application.CreateForm(TDMImageStore, DMImageStore);` takes 7-8 seconds (inside/outside the IDE).
Creating the datamodule later only moves the problem in time.

I assume this is all main thread code, any attempts to make a splash screen with an animation therefore fail.

Is there a way to work around this, e.g. create the datamodule in the background?
On program start the user lands in a menu screen which does not need the images yet, so there is some time for this (e.g. no actions requiring the images until a 'created' flag is set).

Win32 program in Delphi 10.4 Sydney.

(If there is no real way around this I can fall back on a static splash screen with an image.)

Comment: How are you loading the images?

Comment: I doubt you will succeed with the standard DFM streaming, because the underlying mechanism makes heavy use of global variables and objects.

Comment: What I'll say here after could require a lot of changes in your application design depending on the use you do of the images. A way to speedup image access is either to build a large combining all the images or load each image individually as needed, caching them in memory. A 400KB large image should load in a fraction of a second. Then once loaded, you can, on demand, extract part of that large image into the originals ones in individual TBitMap.

Comment: @UweRaabe DFM streaming alone should be threadsafe because it is protected by locks. Whether or not streaming TImageCollection and TVirtualImageList is thread safe that is another questions.

Comment: Seems to go against suggested best practices; "A TVirtualImageList should always be placed on a form, not a data module. Forms have an associated monitor and DPI; data modules do not. A TImageCollection can be placed anywhere, since they are simply the source, and are unaffected by DPI changes: they are the source, while the virtual image list is the presentation." I would review what you are doing as 7-8 seconds is an extremly long to process 400KB of data.

Comment: @sddk They are present at design time, I later lookup up a bitmap by name and assign that to a TImage

Comment: @Brian, yeah this is NOT designed to support multiple monitors with different DPIs. I suspect the VirtualImageList